# ERROR: Error while obtaining start requests - Scrapy

Tags: python, memory, scrapy

When I run the code below, I get these errors : http://pastebin.com/AJqRxCpM
My settings: http://pastebin.com/9nzaXLJs

This is my code:

```
import scrapy

import requests
from scrapy.http import Request

import scrapy
from FinalSpider.items import Page  # Defined in items.py

URL = "http://url.com/PopUp.aspx?IDCoupon=%d"
starting_number = 60000
number_of_pages = 80

class FinalSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "FinalSpider"
    allowed_domains = ['url.com']
    start_urls = [URL % starting_number]

    def __init__(self):
        self.page_number = starting_number

    def start_requests(self):
        for i in range (self.page_number, number_of_pages, -1):
            yield request(url = URL % i, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        filename = response.url.split("/")[-2] + '.html'
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
```

Comment: please share complete log, and settings, by any chance did you setup your own `CONCURRENT_REQUEST` on settings?, maybe it is too high

Comment: Hi eLRuLL , I don't think it's the settings file because i didn't change much. Anyhow, I posted that too. I didn't touch concurrent_request, and i got the same message, then raised it to 100, same message. Then i put it back to default, which is 16.

Comment: Hi, I couldn't fit it in here due to character limit. That's why I used paste bin,

Comment: Ok np. Do you know a way how  I could resolve this ?

Comment: you are yielding `request` on `start_requests`, and it should be `Request`

Comment: I'm getting the same error after I changed that. Anyhow, I have resolved this by adding another code. Thanks either way.

Answer (score 1):

It's resolved. Just add this:

```
start_urls = ['url.com/=%d' %(n)
              for n in range(0, 20)] * MEANS from 0 to 20
```

Comment: Would you please explain?